# Can syslog be configured for Oracle Database Cloud Service?

Tags: oracle, cloud

*Short Version:*
If I create a `Cloud Database` (on `Oracle Database Cloud Service`) -

**1. Can it log to `Syslog`?

 2. Can I set where that `syslog` is located
    (i.e., at which `host:port`)?**

*Long Version:*
If an `Oracle Database` runs on a machine, then I can direct its logs (e.g., audit logs) to either a non-default directory, or to a centralised `syslog` on another machine.

How can I do the same with DBaaS like `Oracle Database Cloud Service?`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can see Syslog using root user. In Oracle cloud machine you cannot login as root directly. But you can login as OPC user and after that switch yourself as root using the sudo command. SYSLOG is located in /var/log/messages. If you installed Oracle management cloud then you can get GUI called "Oracle Log Analytics interface". You can check from this interface.